# MySQL Powershell import

Tags: mysql, powershell, mysqlimport

I have tried everything I can find on existing threads, apologies if this is remedial.

I have an open and working connection to my database for a batch import script. I would like to, in addition to importing users, populate their databases with a preset .sql file.  I have the file in the Bin directory for MySQL on windows C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin and my directory Powershell is running from.

The SQL file imports correctly, if run from mysql 5.7 cli with:

```
Use db_name;

Source db_file.sql
```

Is there a way to do this in my open connection through PS with "CommandText" or do I need to run a separate authenticated command after closing the user import connection?  Here is what IS currently working: I want to add the .sql import at the end.

```
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

$connStr ="server=localhost;Persist Security Info=false;user id=USERNAME" + $dbusername + ";pwd=PASSWORD" + $dbpassword + ";"

$conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connStr)

$conn.Open()

$cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$cmd.Connection  = $conn

$cmd.CommandText = "CREATE USER '$usr'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.CommandText = "CREATE SCHEMA $usr"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.CommandText = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $usr.* TO '$usr'@'%';"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$cmd.CommandText = "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $group.* TO '$usr'@'%';"
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

$conn.Close()
```